Allow login over SSH, but not local password login
I'd like to allow a user to log in over SSH using a public key, but not allow this user to log in from the local console with a password. Is there any way to do this?
A workaround is setting an exceedingly long random password, but I wonder if it can be done in a cleaner way than that.
(Debian Linux, if this matters)

Would they ever need a password once logged in, are you planning on giving them sudo rights?

If the answer to the question above is no, just set their password in /etc/shadow to ! ...
